# how to convert my existing python code into visual GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image: Input to get in GUI is ID number] [image: Output Graph after running series of code for the given input]I have written a code to predict the sales of many products using its previous trend. When I enter the product ID it displays the graph forecasted for that particular item. Now I want to convert this code into GUI where I can input the item id and the graph will be displayed without looking at the backend codes. I have used python for coding.

Comment: hmmm can you reveal the code that you have written, in order to help you with the GUI stuff?

Comment: Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hello. There is the excellent matplotlib package for showing graphs easily: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py